# Change Octave Super Tiny font size

Tags: octave, font-size, octave-gui

I figured out how to change my code editor font size however, Octave GUI tabs and other features have super tiny text that I cannot figure out how to make larger. For example the Documentation tab, the file name tabs, and even when clicking preferences I have super tiny text.

[Super Tiny text in Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCzPt.png)

Comment: For reference, what platform/operating system/Octave version are you working with?