# Octave GUI font size issue on tabs

Tags: user-interface, fonts, size, octave

I have a font issue with Octave 8.4.0 on Windows 10 enterprise 10.0.19045 build 19045 with DELL XPS 15 9500.
I can change the font size of almost all elements through the General/Editor Styles but the tab font size as per attached pix. The Preference window is unreadable.

Is there a fix or what is the way forward please?

So far, my only way out is to use a display text size of 200% with a 3440x1440 screen resolution... so I don't talk about using the laptop screen...

KR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Rg5.jpg)

I am expecting to be able to increase the GUI tabs font size to have it readable as well as other windows, esp. Preferences.

Comment: just noting that a similar issue was reported about a year ago without any followup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756929/change-octave-super-tiny-font-size , but they didn't specify OS/version/etc.  According to octave maintainers (https://octave.discourse.group/t/gui-preferences-dialog-font-sizes/3255/3) it should just be using the system’s font size for the interface font.  do all other system fonts look ok? do you know if any are Qt based applications?  may be worth following up directly over on the Octave discourse thread

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. System font size is fine on all other interfaces. All are mostly default Windows based. What is the link to octave discourse thread please?

Comment: https://octave.discourse.group/t/gui-preferences-dialog-font-sizes/3255/3